# Dynamic growing Matrices inside loops, best strategy for performance

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm developing an estimation algorithm in C++ and **performance is key**. Basically there is loop where in each iteration, a decision is made on whether to add a column vector to a matrix or to remove one.

I have implemented my own matrix and vector classes and used *Intel MKL* for matrix operations. However after the first version I'm now looking into using *Armadillo*.

I would like to know what the best strategy is for dynamic growing matrices inside loops. I know the maximum size of the matrix, so I could preallocate.

- First of all, is there another matrix library you would recommend other than *Armadillo* for small matrices (50 X 50)?
- Secondly, what would be the best way to tackle this problem using *Armadillo*?

Comment: Growing matrices inside loops goes against performance, no matter what library you use. It's better to work out the maximum matrix size, and then keep a track of which columns are active. In the Armadillo library, active columns can be easily accessed via [non-contiguous submatrices](http://arma.sf.net/docs.html#submat), eg. X.cols(vector_of_column_indices). Alternatively (and slower), you can grow/shrink matrices via [.resize()](http://arma.sf.net/docs.html#resize_member), or [.insert_cols()](http://arma.sf.net/docs.html#insert) and [.shed_cols()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#shed)

Comment: Thank you mtall! I think I will take your advice and rewrite the whole algorithm using fixed-sized matrices.